# what's the difference between windowActionBar and android:windowActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

when I set thestyle in this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

the actionbar will go away.

however,when I set it in this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name=“android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

the actionbar is still here.

what's the difference ?

Answer (score 18):

`windowActionBar` is an attribute provided in AppCompat library, where as `android:windowActionBar` is provided in Material theme.

The action bar is going away when you set below code, just because you are using AppCompat library and referring the attribute provided in this library itself:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

On another points, it's same as `colorPrimary` and `android:colorPrimary` attribute and all other similar attributes.

**For example:**

We were using Material theme and referring `android:colorPrimary` attribute as below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        ....
        ....
</style>
```

but we are now using AppCompat library with only `colorPrimary` attribute, for providing compatibility to lower versions.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        ...
        ...

</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

`android:windowActionBar` denotes property for lollipop and above only. Where as `windowActionBar` denotes for all versions and is retrieved from support library.